Installing Google takeout under a different Google account
The site Google Takeout allows you to back up all of your Google data to several takeout files anointing to 2GB each which can be downloaded once ready and backed up to a local pen drive and stored in a safe at home or something like that.
However, I would like to ask, is it possible to store Google takeout files by upload to a different Google account then the one from which the takeouts were created?
For instance, I have an account joedoe@gmail.com with data, I create the takeout there, I create the joedoe2@gmail.com Google account, and then upload my takeout to the joedoe2@gmail.com overwriting everything so that the takeout contents are the joedoe2@gmail.com contents.
In the meantime I might have modified several aspects of my joedoe@gmail.com account, and don't want to overwrite it with the takeout.
Can I do all of this?
Thanks.

The Google Takeout files are not used to restore your Google Account. They will include your current files and email if you choose to include them however it won't be easy to transfer them back.
If your goal is to simply get a copy of your messages and documents between accounts this is not a good approach.
You can however store the Google Takeout files in the other account for safekeeping.
I would suggest doing a bit more research and maybe even download a Takeout archive and browse through it's contents to get a better idea of what it includes.
